# Why is regex search returning None for the same string?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

This code returns None, what am I doing wrong? I'm assuming it has something to do with special characters

```
test=re.search('The Girl Who Played with Fire (Millennium #2)', 'The Girl Who Played with Fire (Millennium #2)',re.IGNORECASE)
print(test)
```

Comment: Parenthesis, `(` and `)`, are special characters in regex used for grouping. You'll need to escape them, `\(` and `\)`, if you want to match them

Comment: @IainShelvington You're right! Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The parenthesis are being treated as grouping operators when the string is used as a pattern.

Try this instead:

```
test=re.search(
    'The Girl Who Played with Fire [(]Millennium #2[)]',
    'The Girl Who Played with Fire (Millennium #2)',
    re.IGNORECASE
)
```

Comment: This works! How do I add the forward slashes before the parentheses using re.sub?

Comment: if you're just looking for whether a string is a substring of another, it will be far easier just to use `in` than to escape strings into regexes for the purpose

Comment: No, I have a list of book titles and I want my code to return True when the user enters a title that is present in my list. My code works with all book titles except for those having parentheses in them, so I'm thinking to re.sub the user's input to escape ( and ) but I've never used re.sub before and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Nevermind, I can just use replace() to do it lol

Answer (score -1):

You have to escape `(` and `)` in Regex:

```
test=re.search(
   'The Girl Who Played with Fire \(Millennium #2\)', # <- NOTICE
   'The Girl Who Played with Fire (Millennium #2)',
   re.IGNORECASE)
print(test)
```